# Future raid update in a NAS

Tags: raid, nas

I'm thinking of buying the HP ProLiant MicroServer*. My question is if I just put a single 2TB drive, how easy would it be in the future to upgrade to a second 2TB drive in a RAID-1 setup? Can this be done without formatting the original 2TB drive?

Comment: Edited so this is not so much a shopping question.

Answer (score 0):

I can not say for sure, since I havent used HP ProLiants in a while.  But if my memory serves my correctly, the RAID configuration page will not let you set up a mirror without at least 2 drives.  Perhaps the software has evolved since I last used it, allowing you to create a broken mirror from the start, but it would not be something I would expect.

Comment: SO there isn't a way to start non-RAID and magically change to RAID after the addition of a second drive.